# Populate JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I want to encode an array in php as JSON. How do I make a proper JSON array?

i want to pass two variables.

```
$var = 33;
$last = 44;
```

and db results:

```
foreach($query->result() as $r)
{
    $data[]= $r; //popunjava niz rezultatima 
}
```

i am trying to make JSON like this:

```
$data='';
$data[] =$last;
$data[] =$pn;

foreach($query->result() as $r)
{
    $data[]= $r; //popunjava niz rezultatima 
}

    echo json_encode($data);  // json enkoduje niz i pomocu echo prosledjuje do ajaxa
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: i get results [8,1{"id":"8","info":"London"}]

Comment: i think its not valid JSON

Comment: What JSON were you wanting to get, if the results aren't want you intended?

Comment: @VladimirŠtus — Are you sure there isn't a comma after the first `1`?

Comment: To check the validity of the JSON, use a [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Can you tell us what is the expected JSON that you wanted? The result you currently get is correct based on the code you have showed.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_push to append rows onto the array.

```
$data = array();
foreach($query->result() as $r)
{
    array_push($data, $r);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Why? Doesn't that do the same as `$data[]=`?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a key in the array for the variables that you add.

```
$data= array();
$data['last'] = $last;
$data['pn'] = $pn;

foreach($query->result() as $r)
{
    $data['results'][] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```